# Build dynamic DataTable

Tags: flutter

I need to build a dynamic dataTable.

```
class _MyGridState extends State<MyGrid> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return

      DataTable(columns: getDataColumn(),
          rows: getRows()
      )
  }
}
 Future List<DataColumn>  getDataColumn() async  {

    await WebSignIn('Myuser@gmail.com', 'XXXX');
    DocumentSnapshot ds = await getSingleDocument(
        'www.xyzz.com', 'aa');
    List<DataColumn> resultDC = new List<DataColumn>();


    ds.data.forEach((f, d) {
      DataColumn dc = new DataColumn(label:Text(f.toString()),tooltip:d.toString() );
      resultDC.add(dc);

    });
```

Both functions return List objects.
The problem is that both getDataColumn and GetRows function should be an async function (get the data form net).
and make them async will cause an error 'Method must have and explicit list of parameters' + I will have to make the returned object future type (will cause an error with the expected DataTable return data type.
What should I do?

Thank you!

Comment: can you add getDataColumn and getRows functions ?

Comment: I added the getDataColumn function (the getRows() is almost the same). I got lot's of a mistakes on this getDataColumn implementation including:1) List<DataColumn> must have an explicit list of parameters 2)List<DataColumn> resultDC - list isn't a type and more...